# Hovering on Rounded-Corners Element

Tags: html, css, hover, rounded-corners

Say a have a div, and that I rounded its corners so it became a circle. Now, I want to apply the `:hover` pseudo-element to it. But I have other elements surrounding it, which in turn have `:hover` effects themselves. I only want the hover effect of the circle to activate if the mouse is effectively inside the circle.

To illustrate this problem:

[image: Div into a circle after border-radius has been applied]

The square was my div, and the circle how it looked after rounding its corners. Pretend that the black areas are in front of other elements, whose `:hover` effect I also want to be able to use. If I apply the hover pseudo-element to the circle, when the mouse is in a black zone, the circle's hover effect will be activated, and not the one of the element behind the div...

How to (if it can be done) solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting? see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yfW5s/1/

Comment: You see, the idea is exactly that the hover effect only happens if I hover **on the circle**, not on the surrounding square... does this help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did a [**little test**](http://jsbin.com/lupef/1) on the latest versions of Chrome, Opera, Firefox, IE and Safari; besides Opera*, the browsers seem to work as you would wish.

Opera doesn't, and that's due to faulty browser implementation, and should be filed as a bug. The [**specs**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#corner-clipping) are pretty clear on this point:

> Also, the area outside the curve of the border edge does not accept pointer events on behalf of the element.

<sub>P.S. (The :hover is a pseudo-class, not a pseudo-element)</sub>

<sub>* When I originally made this post I tested the issue on the latest version of Opera on **Linux** which currently is 12.16. As [King King pointed out below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621207/hovering-on-rounded-corners-element#comment36268070_23621312), this is not the latest version on other operating system, where the test works fine.</sub>

Comment: Same results here: See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N9F44/) for another example.

Comment: Wow, that's interesting... after having a very very close look at code, I think I have found out the issue: I am working with percentages. As such to make a circle I have to use a :before, e.g. `.circle:before {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 padding-top: 100%;  /* ratio of 1:1 */
}` Is this what's causing this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Can you make a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) of your case? You can edit my own test, if you wish. I am not sure exactly how you are implementing it before you post the relevant code, but keep in mind that the `padding` is indeed part of the element and accepts pointer events.

Comment: Oh sir/ma'am, you are indeed very very very knowledgeable ;D Simply, I was doing this: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jacohegi/1/) . Replacing padding-top with margin-top completely solved it! I don't know how I hadn't thought of that! Thanks!

Comment: Glad I helped you. Be aware, however, that this still doesn't work correctly in Opera. But that's a bug, and you should file it ;).

Comment: why do you think Opera has a bug here? At least the latest version (21) treats it in a normal way, hovering on the square corner just changes the background color of the `.behind`, while hovering on the circle of course changes the background color of the `.circle`. It works OK without any bug. Looks like you tested it on some **older** version of Opera. BTW, since now, if Opera has a bug, there is a **high chance** that Chrome will have the same bug. Now Chrome and Opera are very similar browsers in the way of rendering page.

Comment: Latest version on [Linux was 12.16](http://www.opera.com/docs/history/), and that's where I tested. Downloading the version you mention on Mac Os X indeed works correctly. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use SVG your element will be whatever you define it to be, and it's bounded by the border shape/size of your of your specs. So in your case a circle you can do something like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="50" y2="50" stroke="red" class="circle" />
</svg>
```

and then style it with css:

```
.circle:hover {
    stroke: blue
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8nZmM/1/)